# Unable to see tables in my airpal homepage

Tags: presto

[image]
i cant access tables in airpal homepage. Can anyone help me out from this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide some more details about the environment setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can at first check the airpal log,
I have the same problem like you.
I checked my logs, and founded that our Airpal didn't recognize our customized Serde classes